# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.example.demo.Database.Database.getName()' on a null object reference in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am going to call the getName() method in my database. But this error display.

Here my code

[image: MainActivity.java] MainActivity.java

[image: Database.java] Database.java

Run-time Error

> 04-19 09:46:07.513 12758-12758/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.demo, PID: 12758
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo/com.example.demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.example.demo.Database.Database.getName()' on a null object reference
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.example.demo.Database.Database.getName()' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.demo.MainActivity.LoadSuggestList(MainActivity.java:98)
>           at com.example.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not justify the "database" element. To solve this, simple use `Database database = new Database();`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this `Database database = new Database(this);` but there is a new error again. `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference`

Comment: All this "null object reference" errors appears because you need to justify all elements. Edit your question or open a new question with details of this new error and I will help you again.